# Argument not returned for some options

Tags: pdftex, expl3, latex3, strings

When using one option of a `\str_case` for the case `noseperator` the returned string is empty. I do not understand why...

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[mode=text, reset-text-series = false, separate-uncertainty, group-digits=integer, group-minimum-digits = 4]{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator = {\,}, input-decimal-markers={,.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \g__eur_length_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\setcurrencyformat}{m}
{
    \str_gset:Nn \g__eur_length_str { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EUR}{om}
{
    \currency_print_value:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { € }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\currency}{om}
{
    \currency_print_value:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { }
}


\cs_new_protected:Nn \currency_print_value:nnn
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {% no optional argument
        \currency_print:Vnn \g__eur_length_str { #2 } { #3 }
    }
    {% optional argument present
        \currency_print:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
    }
}

\tl_new:N \l__currency_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \currency_print:nnn
{
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {#3} { }
    { % empty
        \tl_set:Nn \l__currency_temp_tl {}
    }
    { % not empty
        \tl_set:Nn \l__currency_temp_tl { \nobreakspace \unit{#3} }
    }
    
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
    {
        { full }    { \num[group-separator = {.}, minimum-decimal-digits = 2]{#2} \tl_use:N \l__currency_temp_tl }
        { standard }{ \num[group-separator = {.}, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]{#2} \tl_use:N \l__currency_temp_tl }     
        { min }     { \num[group-separator = {.}, round-mode = places, round-precision = 0]{#2} \tl_use:N \l__currency_temp_tl }
        { noseperator }  { #2 \tl_use:N \l__currency_temp_tl }  % <= returns nothing
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \currency_print:nnn { V }

\setcurrencyformat{full}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
        \currency[noseparator]{123.45678} (currency[noseparator])  % <= returns nothing
        
        \EUR[noseparator]{123.45678} (EUR[noseparator]) % <= returns nothing
        
        \currency{123.45678} (currency)     
        
        \currency[full]{123.45678} (currency[full]) 
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: `noseperator `  is not `noseparator`

Comment: #fail.... I though I had checked this multiple times... Thanks. It does solve this MWE but it does not solve my original problem... I will create a new question for this.

Comment: Please, avoid `scrlttr2` for examples. Use `article`, if the example isn't about a specific class.

Comment: @egreg: Why should I avoid it? It is the target class for the code. Since there are so many intereconnections between the packages more than once the solution for my MWE did not work in the real example because I changed too much. I do see no harm in leaving the example being `scrlttr2`...

Comment: @mrCarnivore because MWEs (minimal working example) should show the problem without unnecessary extra. The KOMA classes are more complex and redefine things and if the problem can be exhibited without them then it is better not to use them as it makes debugging a problem more difficult. You should really try to do the first step and drop everything from an example that doesn't make your problem go away.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I have done that multiple times. Most of the time the result was that the solution provided worked with the MWE but not with my original problem. That is very frustrating. I do try to find a middle ground to remove everything that is not needed but struggle to define what might have an impact and what does not...

Comment: @mrCarnivore don't forget that if you don't do this (and learn along the way) then those who try to help you have to do that (and all of them)  to get down to your problem. So a) it means work of one against work of many and b)  -- hint -- people may loose interest in helping you if they don't see that you make a reasonable effort. I'm not saying this is always easy and nobody will push you hard if you fail to do so fully but ...

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I fully understand that and appreciate the help I am getting here a lot! I did shorten the example in the post quite a bit compared to my real code. I also completely understand that it is bad to save time yourself and because of that require others to work more. That is not my intent! Like I said: Before I shortened the examples too much and even though I got an answer my real problem remained unsolved. This lead to unneccessary additional questions that I tried to prevent. I shortened the example and removed the (hopefully) still unneccesary code. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noseperator`   is not `noseparator`